# How to ignore hidden files with opendir and readdir in C library

Tags: c, unix, file-io

Here is some simple code:

```
DIR* pd = opendir(xxxx);
struct dirent *cur;
while (cur = readdir(pd)) puts(cur->d_name);
```

What I get is kind of messy: including dot (`.`), dot-dot (`..`) and file names that end with `~`.

I want to do exactly the same thing as the command `ls`. How do I fix this, please?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is normal. If you do `ls -a` (which shows all files, `ls -A` will show all files except for `.` and `..`), you will see the same output.

`.` is a link referring to the directory it is in: `foo/bar/.` is the same thing is `foo/bar`.

`..` is a link referring to the parent directory of the directory it is in: `foo/bar/..` is the same thing as `foo`.

Any other files beginning with `.` are hidden files (by convention, it is not really enforced by anything; this is different from Windows, where there is a real, official hidden attribute). Files ending with `~` are probably backup files created by your text editor (again, this is convention, these really *could* be anything).

If you don't want to show these types of files, you have to explicitly check for them and ignore them.

Comment: +1. Just insert the text "if (*cur->d_name != '.') " in front of "puts(...)" to get the default behaviour of ls.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: if he doesn't want backup files, he would also have to check for the trailing ~.

Comment: thank all of you! I would like to choose all answers if I could. now, I hava completely understood this matter. thank you, again!

Comment: how do we ignore folders?

Answer (score 7):

Eliminating hidden files:

```
DIR* pd = opendir(xxxx);
struct dirent *cur;
while (cur = readdir(pd)) {
    if (cur->d_name[0] != '.') {
        puts(cur->d_name);
    }
}
```

Eliminating hidden files and files ending in "~":

```
DIR* pd = opendir(xxxx);
struct dirent *cur;
while (cur = readdir(pd)) {
    if (cur->d_name[0] != '.' && cur->d_name[strlen(cur->d_name)-1] != '~') {
        puts(cur->d_name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Stick a `if (cur->d_name[0] != '.')` before you process the name.

The UNIX hidden file standard is the leading dot, which `.` and `..` also match.

The trailing `~` is the standard for backup files.  It's a little more work to ignore those, but a multi-gigahertz CPU can manage it.  Use something like `if (cur->d_name[strlen(cur->d_name)-1] == '~')`

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is *exactly* like what `ls -a` does. If you want filtering then you'll need to do it after the fact.