# reading files in a directory C++

Tags: c++

I'm reading files in a directory and passing it to a function, I think I'm doing it in a wrong way, not able to figure out.

Here is my code first it reads files in a folder and send it to a function for further operations.

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
std::vector<std::string> fileName;


int main(void) 
{

 DIR           *d;
 struct dirent *dir;
 vector<string> fileList;
 int i=0;
 d = opendir("files");
 if (d)
 {
 while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
 {
 i++;
 fileList.push_back(dir->d_name);

 }
 for(int i=0;i<fileList.size();i++) {
  cout<<fileList[i]<<endl;
  doSomething(fileList[i]);
 }
 closedir(d);
  }

 return(0);
 }

 int doSomething(fileName) {
 //do something
 }
```

Error

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:29:28: error: ‘doSomething’ was not declared in this scope
 doSomething(fileList[i]);
                        ^
main.cpp: At global scope:
main.cpp:37:26: error: cannot convert       ‘std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >’ to ‘int’ in initialization
int doSomething(fileName) {
                      ^
main.cpp:37:28: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
int doSomething(fileName) {
                        ^
```

Comment: If you format your code more consistently and using indentation people may be more likely to try to figure out what you did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `doSomething` function is defined after main, it is not visible, that causes the first error. The correct way would be to at least declare the function first:

```
int doSomething(); //declaration

int main()
{
    doSomething(); //now the function is declared 
}

//definition
int doSomething()
{
}
```

Now, the second and third errors is emited because you didn't include the `fileName` parameter's type in your function definition. Based on your code, it should be a string:

```
int doSomething(string fileName)
{
}
```

I also noticed that, while this function returns `int`, you are not using it's returned value. Nevertheless, don't forget to `return` something from `doSomething`, otherwise it will cause undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks it worked just one last question. Above program outputs like this
`file1.txt` 
`file2.txt`
`.`  
and `..`
My folder has only two files it outputting two extra values '.' and '..'

Comment: @ronroo, `.` is "current folder", and `..` is "folder that contains the current folder".

Comment: Is it possible to avoid it? it might effect for further operation.

Comment: @ronroo, check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845556/how-to-ignore-hidden-files-with-opendir-and-readdir-in-c-library

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Boost is great, but it's a bit bloaty. So, just for completenessapplied to reading images in a directory for OpenCV:

```
// you need these includes for the function
//#include <windows.h> // for windows systems
#include <dirent.h> // for linux systems
#include <sys/stat.h> // for linux systems
#include <algorithm>    // std::sort
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>   //cout

using namespace std;

/* Returns a list of files in a directory (except the ones that begin with a dot) */
int readFilenames(std::vector<string> &filenames, const string &directory)
{
#ifdef WINDOWS
    HANDLE dir;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA file_data;

    if ((dir = FindFirstFile((directory + "/*").c_str(), &file_data)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return; /* No files found */

    do {
        const string file_name = file_data.cFileName;
        const string full_file_name = directory + "/" + file_name;
        const bool is_directory = (file_data.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) != 0;

        if (file_name[0] == '.')
            continue;

        if (is_directory)
            continue;

        filenames.push_back(full_file_name);
    } while (FindNextFile(dir, &file_data));

    FindClose(dir);
#else
    DIR *dir;
    class dirent *ent;
    class stat st;

    dir = opendir(directory.c_str());
    while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        const string file_name = ent->d_name;
        const string full_file_name = directory + "/" + file_name;

        if (file_name[0] == '.')
            continue;

        if (stat(full_file_name.c_str(), &st) == -1)
            continue;

        const bool is_directory = (st.st_mode & S_IFDIR) != 0;

        if (is_directory)
            continue;

//        filenames.push_back(full_file_name); // returns full path
        filenames.push_back(file_name); // returns just filename
    }
    closedir(dir);
#endif
    std::sort (filenames.begin(), filenames.end()); //optional, sort the filenames
    return(filenames.size()); //Return how many we found
} // GetFilesInDirectory


void help(const char **argv) {
  cout << "\n\n"
       << "Call:\n" << argv[0] << " <directory path>\n\n"
       << "Given a directory of images, create a vector of\n"
       << "their names, read and display them. Filter out\n"
       << "non-images\n"
       << endl;
}

int main( int argc, const char** argv )
{
    if(argc != 2) {
        cerr << "\nIncorrect number of parameters: " << argc << ", should be 2\n" << endl;
        help(argv);
        return -1;
    }
    string folder = argv[1];
    cout << "Reading in directory " << folder << endl;
    vector<string> filenames;

    int num_files = readFilenames(filenames, folder);
    cout << "Number of files = " << num_files << endl;
    cv::namedWindow( "image", 1 );
    for(size_t i = 0; i < filenames.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout << folder + filenames[i] << " #" << i << endl;
        cv::Mat src = cv::imread(folder + filenames[i]);

        if(!src.data) { //Protect against no file
            cerr << folder + filenames[i] << ", file #" << i << ", is not an image" << endl;
            continue;
        }
        cv::imshow("image", src);
        cv::waitKey(250); //For fun, wait 250ms, or a quarter of a second, but you can put in "0" for no wait or -1 to wait for keypresses
        /* do whatever you want with your images here */
    }
}
```